# cancel the iOS Subscription

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am already subscribed to 12 month subscription and in the middle of subscription i want to subscribed to 1 month subscription. I am showing alert to user that you have remaining days of your existing subscription. But what if user still want to purchase the subscription. Can I Cancel the subscription through programming so that user can purchase new subscription.

In Background, I have two subscription of same group . One of 12 month subscription and other is 1 month subscription.

Comment: Are you using auto-renewing subscriptions or non-renewing subscriptions?

Comment: Auto renewing subscription

Comment: that aslo depends on what kind of groups structure do you have. If you have one group then don't worry about my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Any changes to the subscription renewal frequency will come into effect at the end of the current period.

If the user has six months remaining on an annual subscription and then subscribes to a monthly subscription then in six months time, when the annual subscription expires, their subscription will be renewed for one month and each month thereafter until they cancel their subscription or change the period again.

It is important that you set up your related subscriptions in the same subscription group. Assuming that both the annual subscription and monthly subscription are at the same level within the subscription group, the scenario you are describing is considered a [cross-grade](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW11):

> - **Crossgrade**. When a customer switches between subscriptions within the same level. If the in-app purchases are of the same duration, the customer’s prorated amount from the prior in-app purchase is refunded to the original payment method. The new in-app purchase is charged and goes into effect immediately at the full price, which changes the customer’s renewal date to the upgrade date. *If the in-app purchase are of different durations, the crossgrade goes into effect on the customer’s next renewal date*.